# Wifidirect Discovery not finding peers

Tags: java, android-fragments, bluetooth, wifi-direct

I got an wifidirect app that sucessfully discovers and connects to a peer , i "attached" that app to another app that i am developing . That app it supposed to control a robot with bluetooth and comunicate via Wifidirect at the same time , it has a " play button " and when it is clicked ,it goes to another activity , that activity has two fragments , one is the first to appear after the " play" button was clicked and obligates the user to connect to a peer( thats were i attached the wifidirect app) , after connecting it goes to the second fragment , this fragment has the game interface , it has all the bluetooth part (connecting and controling the robot ) .

In summary : First activity has a play button , button clicked , it goes to the second activity with the two fragments . The second activity , has to connect to a peer with Wifidirect and after that it has to connect and control a robot with bluetooth .

In the second activity is happening WifiDirect and Bluetooth comunication at the same time (confusing... i know )

My problem : If i solely use the Wifidirect app , it searchs and connects sucessfully  but with the "fusion" of both apps , it just searchs forever without finding nothing .Any idea of whats happening ? maybe to much comunication or to many things happening in the same activity? If im being confusing please tell me.

My Wifidiscovery activity :

```
public class WiFiServiceDiscoveryActivity extends Activity implements
    DeviceClickListener, Handler.Callback, MessageTarget,
    ConnectionInfoListener {

public static final String TAG = "wifidirectdemo";

// TXT RECORD properties
public static final String TXTRECORD_PROP_AVAILABLE = "available";
public static final String SERVICE_INSTANCE = "_wifidemotest";
public static final String SERVICE_REG_TYPE = "_presence._tcp";

public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 0x400 + 1;
public static final int MY_HANDLE = 0x400 + 2;
private WifiP2pManager manager;

static final int SERVER_PORT = 4545;

private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
private Channel channel;
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;
private WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest serviceRequest;

private Handler handler = new Handler(this);
private jogar chatFragment;
private WiFiDirectServicesList servicesList;

private TextView statusTxtView;
Button botaorecomecar;

public Handler getHandler() {
    return handler;
}

public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    statusTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);
    botaorecomecar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaorecomecar);

    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter
            .addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter
            .addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
    startRegistrationAndDiscovery();

    servicesList = new WiFiDirectServicesList();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container_root, servicesList, "services").commit();

    botaorecomecar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }


    });}





@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    Fragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("services");
    if (frag != null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();
    }
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if (manager != null && channel != null) {
        manager.removeGroup(channel, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Disconecção falhada. Razão: :" + reasonCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
            }

        });
    }
    super.onStop();
}

/**
 * Registers a local service and then initiates a service discovery
 */
private void startRegistrationAndDiscovery() {
    Map<String, String> record = new HashMap<String, String>();
    record.put(TXTRECORD_PROP_AVAILABLE, "visivel");

    WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo service = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo.newInstance(
            SERVICE_INSTANCE, SERVICE_REG_TYPE, record);
    manager.addLocalService(channel, service, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            appendStatus("Serviço local adicionado");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int error) {
            appendStatus("Falha ao adicionar serviço");
        }
    });

    discoverService();

}

private void discoverService() {

    /*
     * Register listeners for DNS-SD services. These are callbacks invoked
     * by the system when a service is actually discovered.
     */

    manager.setDnsSdResponseListeners(channel,
            new DnsSdServiceResponseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDnsSdServiceAvailable(String instanceName,
                                                    String registrationType, WifiP2pDevice srcDevice) {

                    // A service has been discovered. Is this our app?

                    if (instanceName.equalsIgnoreCase(SERVICE_INSTANCE)) {

                        // update the UI and add the item the discovered
                        // device.
                        WiFiDirectServicesList fragment = (WiFiDirectServicesList) getFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentByTag("serviços");
                        if (fragment != null) {
                            WiFiDevicesAdapter adapter = ((WiFiDevicesAdapter) fragment
                                    .getListAdapter());
                            WiFiP2pService service = new WiFiP2pService();
                            service.device = srcDevice;
                            service.instanceName = instanceName;
                            service.serviceRegistrationType = registrationType;
                            adapter.add(service);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Log.d(TAG, "onBonjourServiceAvailable "
                                    + instanceName);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }, new DnsSdTxtRecordListener() {

                /**
                 * A new TXT record is available. Pick up the advertised
                 * buddy name.
                 */
                @Override
                public void onDnsSdTxtRecordAvailable(
                        String fullDomainName, Map<String, String> record,
                        WifiP2pDevice device) {
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            device.deviceName + " é "
                                    + record.get(TXTRECORD_PROP_AVAILABLE));
                }
            });

    // After attaching listeners, create a service request and initiate
    // discovery.
    serviceRequest = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest.newInstance();
    manager.addServiceRequest(channel, serviceRequest,
            new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    appendStatus("Adicionado pedido de descoberta de serviços");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int arg0) {
                    appendStatus("Falha ao adicionar pedido de descoberta de serviços");
                }
            });
    manager.discoverServices(channel, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            appendStatus("Descoberta de serviços iniciada");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int arg0) {
            appendStatus("Descoberta de serviços falhada");

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void connectP2p(WiFiP2pService service) {
    WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
    config.deviceAddress = service.device.deviceAddress;
    config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
    if (serviceRequest != null)
        manager.removeServiceRequest(channel, serviceRequest,
                new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int arg0) {
                    }
                });

    manager.connect(channel, config, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            appendStatus("A conectar a um serviço");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int errorCode) {
            appendStatus("Falha ao conectar a serviço");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            Log.d(TAG, readMessage);
            (chatFragment).pushMessage(readMessage);
            break;

        case MY_HANDLE:
            Object obj = msg.obj;
            (chatFragment).setChatManager((ChatManager) obj);

    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    receiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(manager, channel, this);
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo p2pInfo) {
    Thread handler = null;
    /*
     * The group owner accepts connections using a server socket and then spawns a
     * client socket for every client. This is handled by {@code
     * GroupOwnerSocketHandler}
     */

    if (p2pInfo.isGroupOwner) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Conectado como GroupOwner");
        try {
            handler = new GroupOwnerSocketHandler(
                    ((MessageTarget) this).getHandler());
            handler.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "Falha ao criar uma thread de servidor - " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Conectado como peer");
        handler = new ClientSocketHandler(
                ((MessageTarget) this).getHandler(),
                p2pInfo.groupOwnerAddress);
        handler.start();
    }
    chatFragment = new jogar();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container_root, chatFragment).commit();
    statusTxtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public void appendStatus(String status) {
    String current = statusTxtView.getText().toString();
    statusTxtView.setText(current + "\n" + status);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct and should work as expected. However, I see one case that can cause the service to be ignored (from your code above):

```
 // A service has been discovered. Is this our app?

 if (instanceName.equalsIgnoreCase(SERVICE_INSTANCE)) {
```

When a service is discovered your app is filtering them by service name, I think the confusion between both apps is that they are using different service names.
Can you try to remove this "if" statement and test the app again?

Hope this helps,

Goodluck.